# Am I responsible if a low-skilled friend joins my company and fails to do his job?

Tags: colleagues, performance, new-hires, ex-colleagues

I worked in a company some years ago where I met with this person, who became one of my friends also outside the workplace. When I left that company we kept in contact with each other of what we are doing, the family and stuff like that.
I am a developer, he is too, but to be honest he is a very weak one.

Now I'm working at my company, a good one and I always told him it is a good workplace, satisfying with projects and so on. The problem arose when he lost the previous job and attempted to join my current company... because we are friends I didn't tell him he was not good enough, since I was 99% sure he wouldn't pass the tech interview at all.
I was informed by my friend that he was hired, and that during the interview he mentioned that he knew about this job by me, and he was a colleague of mine and stuff like that.

I talked with HR, who told me my recommendation was enough for the job.
How to handle this situation when I know he isn't going to perform well?

EDIT: i did not give such a recommendation for my friend, i just know that he told HR was a friend of mine, our urriculum stated we worked in the same company and so on...i know my HR assumed something without telling me anything...

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please edit to explain what you mean by "handle my position on his failure"? Also, he has not yet failed. Why not just wait and see what problems develop? For now, voting to close as unclear.

Comment: You say: "HR that told me mine recmmndation was enough for the job" - did you actually give a recommendation or not?

Comment: I'm strongly assuming that he's been hired, as OP stated: "I was informed by my friend that he was hired".

Comment: This is why the difference between a *reference* and a *recommendation* is very important.

Comment: Now that he's on-board this could be a good opportunity to help him improve.

Comment: Capitals and and real sentences please.

Comment: So HR think you recommended him when you didn't?  The difficulty here is that if you got HR now and tell them you weren't recommending this person, they're going to wonder why you didn't correct this confusion at the time of the original conversation.

Answer (score 6):

I would leave him to do his own job. It will become apparent very soon if he is inadequate for the position. He may have gotten better since you worked together in the past.

So, there is no responsibility on you. If the company hired him independently from you, then it's not your responsibility if he is unsuccessful.

Comment: But HR said that his recommendation was why his friend was hired. Whether or not he was directly involved, that could still be held against him.

Comment: The original post gave me a different understanding of the question. If the OP clarifies and says he was involved and did give a reference for his friend, then I will delete this answer.

Comment: Exactly, it's not your problem to interfere, if HR wanted your recommendation, they would have asked you for one. In fact they didn't. It's like I got a job saying Bill Gates will vouch for me, and no one verified the info, your HR is incompetent.

Comment: But if HR is incompetent, they might also be too incompetent to realize that this is their mess, and take it out on OP.

Comment: @Erik One has to assume that there is some degree of sanity on the parts of the people involved. If it's the case where HR is incompetent, then the OP has bigger problems with his company in general.  If they ask a question in a few days "HR blames me for the failure of my friend to do his work" then that will be addressed on its own merits.

Answer (score 3):

> I was informed by my friend that he was hired

He's been hired, there's nothing to be done from here.

When a friend wishes to join the company you tell them to apply and that you'll put in a good word for them if needed but only if you truly intend to do so. If you don't intend to do that you can say that you'll see what you can do. If you don't feel like giving a recommendation it was simply what you could do. You can limit which relative information you wish to reveal. That means you can  tell them about the actual qualities of having him on-board. Maybe he's a likable guy who's easy to work with, etc.

These things are valuable. His actual skills should be measured by a neutral person and your friend should receive a salary that matches that. Maybe they're very well aware of his skill-set but they're happy to have a solid guy on-board that they can train. You can put in a good word about his skill-set too if you know that it's very good but if you know it's the other way around or you're simply not sure, simply say that you've not been in place to evaluate that specifically.

You're past this part of the process now. Don't worry about the outcome, just make sure you don't lie about qualities or skills in these scenarios and you should have nothing to worry about. Even if he gets the boot one day for not delivering it should not affect your position in the company unless it's a very bad one, as long as you did not lie about the person's skill-set and lacking that skill-set was the cause of him getting fired.

Be happy that your friend is on-board. Help him to adapt to the new environment and make the best out of it. Remember that you can't change the past but you can change the future.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your HR and talk about your experiences with him. However I would not try to downtalk him. Talk about your experiences with him at the previous company and how you worked together. Since you became friends I'm going to assume that you co-operated ok together. Even if he's weaker than you, he may still be a valuable asset to the company, consider him as such.

Do you think he'll be able to contribute to the company? If yes, by how much? Simply saying he's able to contribute to the company should be a good reccomendation from you. You don't need to play him up to be as good as you are. Talk about how good you think his skills are, etc etc.

**Please talk to HR**. If you don't inform HR about anything they will assume you agree with the reccomendation. When he screws up it'll be reflected on you. If you talk to HR about what he CAN do, then they will have a more realistic view on what he can and can't do.

Comment: Talk to RH? "Hey RH, you screwed up". Better talk to your boss: "yes, he is my good friend, let's see if he's a good programmer also".

Comment: @Fernando you could always word it better... However if this friend of his ends up screwing up, then HR will never believe a single recommendation he'd ever make. it'd hurt his reputation. So he needs to be able to make a disclaimer on his recommendation.